# PHP preg_replace not working for this pattern

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have this code:

```
<?php 

$asd = "#13;";

$asd = preg_replace( "/&#?[a-z0-9]{2,8};/i", "", $asd ); 

echo $asd;

?>
```

The result is #13;

the pattern is like html entities;

Why the string is not affected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

shouldn't that be

```
$asd = preg_replace( "/[&#]?[a-z0-9]{2,8};/i", "", $asd );
```

The expected result then is `""` - it's a bit unclear what you're heading for ...

Comment: it should work for both patterns that stars with # or &

Comment: Then it should start `"/^[&#]?[a-...`